# $k$-Correspondences of $n$-Categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory

Consider the $k$-correspondences of $n$-categories. With that I mean the objects of the category defined in [Definition 5.1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1112.0040.pdf#page11) of Barwick‘s and Schommer-Pries‘ unicity paper, that is the $(n + 1)$-category $\mathrm{Gaunt}_n/C_k,$ where $C_k$ is the the $k$-cell and $\mathrm{Gaunt}_n$ is the $(n + 1)$-category of $n$-categories which have isomorphisms being only the identities. The enrichment is via the pullback right before the definition in the paper.

Later in Definition 5.3, another definition is given. A $k$-correspondence of $n$-categories is now a triple $U(X_0, X_1, F)$ of two $n$-categories $X_0, X_1$ together with a functor $F \colon X_0^\mathrm{op} \times X_1 \to \mathrm{Corr}_{n - 1}^{k - 1},$ where $\mathrm{Corr}_{n - 1}^{k - 1}$ the category of $(k - 1)$-correspondences and morphisms are two functors and a transformation in the obvious diagram as described in the article. The way to relate them is more or less the usual straightening equivalence. But it appears to me that the second definition only defines a $1$-category a priori. How do you get the higher morphisms from this?

One possibility would be, that the statement just asserts an equivalence of $1$-categories. But the problem is, using the notation from the article, that the induction is a bit difficult then. In the definition of $U(X_0, X_1, F) \to C_k,$ which should correspond to $(X_0, X_1, F)$ in the other definition, one needs that needs that $F$ is a functor of $n$-categories. Otherwise I do not see how to define the composition of two higher cells if one lies over the endpoints of $C_k$ and the other goes between the fibers.